# PHP convert echo into a variable for re-use

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I know this is basic PHP but I can't find an answer to my conundrum.

I have the following IF statement:

```
<?php if ( in_category(7)) { echo 'f' } elseif ( in_category(6)) { echo 'e' } elseif ( in_category(3)) { echo 'b' } elseif ( in_category(1)) {  echo 'a' } elseif ( in_category(5)) { echo 'd' } elseif ( in_category(8)) { echo 'g' } elseif ( in_category(4)) { echo 'c' } ?>
```

Where I currently echo a letter, I would instead like to store that echo in a variable so I can echo that variable and re-use within the rest of my page.

How would I re-write the above to store the result as a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple put it into a variable?

```
if (in_category(7)) {
    $var = 'f';
} elseif (in_category(6)) {
    $var = 'e';
} elseif (in_category(3)) {
    $var = 'b';
} elseif (in_category(1)) {
    $var = 'a';
} elseif (in_category(5)) {
    $var = 'd';
} elseif (in_category(8)) {
    $var = 'g';
} elseif (in_category(4)) {
    $var = 'c';
} 
echo $var;
```

But I suggest you to create an array for this, and get the value of the array by key:

```
$items = array(
    7 => 'f',
    6 => 'e',
    3 => 'b'
    //and so on
);

$var = $items[6];
//Do whatever
echo $var;
//Output will be: e
```

Comment: this wouldn't work on multiple category assignments, since in_category(7) and in_category(6) would produce "fe" on his question but only "e" on your answer since you overwrite the variable. See my answer / use $var .= 'x' instead of $var = 'X'

Comment: You are wrong. Please check how `else /elseif` works. It's like a `switch / case`. If it goes to any `case`, then it will skip the others, so it will be never `fe` or something like that.

Comment: that's my problem with writing before thinking: I didn't even notice that, so, you're right.